# Return JSON data from a WCF service with netTcpBinding

Tags: jquery, wcf, json, nettcpbinding

I'm creating a WCF service that I would like to return JSON data from. I'd also like to call the service and retrieve the data using jQuery. My problem is that my company only allows netTcpBinding when hosting WCF projects. Anything I've read about returning JSON data from WCF points to using webHttpBinding. So

1. Is it possible to return JSON from a WCF service that uses netTcpBinding?
2. Can I add multiple endpoints using different bindings that point to the same service?
3. If I have a complex class containing other child classes can this be returned using JSON?

(As an aside I'm using the [web service software factory](http://servicefactory.codeplex.com/) to create the service, so I'm not sure if this will make it more difficult having to use Message contracts and all the rest).

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented WCF , Jquery , Json recently in one of my projects. you can do the following things

1) Write your wcf serverics
2) you can expose multiple end points. you need to expose this particular service as jsonp end poing
3) When you expose your services as jsonp endpoing all the method return types will be automatically converted to jsonp objects

you will run into some cross domain issues so please the following link

http://jasonkelly.net/2009/05/using-jquery-jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax-with-wcf-services/

if you want working example  access this url http://www.art.com/gallery/id--b1823/animals-posters.htm?ui=8A93D7DFA9A544E1A91D826217FC4D7B

and then mouseover any image and click one of the directoins , it will make a ajax call to wcf service which returns jsonp

let me know if you need any more info on this.

Comment: Hi gov thanks for the reply. So you're saying that json data can be returned from a netTcpBinding endpoint?